# Buscar quien es el actor que conduce el coche que más veces aparece en un listado de peliculas películas

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, modelorelacional

Necesito hacer la siguiente consulta a Base de Datos: Dado un grupo o listado de películas, buscar quien es el actor que conduce el coche que más veces aparece en este grupo o listado de películas.

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT actor.name
FROM actor
INNER JOIN film
ON actor.id=film.idActor
INNER JOIN car
ON film.id=car.idFilm
WHERE film.title IN ('Fast And Furious','Death proof','Drive')
GROUP BY actor.name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT car.id);
```

Este es el resultado que obtengo con esta consulta:
Name:

Vin Diesel

Pero creo que no es correcto el resultado que muestra anteriormente.

Estructura tabla film:

```
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `film` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `director` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `idActor` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `idCar` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK_film_actor` (`idActor`),
  KEY `FK_film_car` (`idCar`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Estructura tabla actor:

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `actor` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `height` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `age` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `idFilm` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `idCar` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK_actor_starships` (`idCar`),
  KEY `FK_actor_films` (`idFilm`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Estructura tabla car:

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `car` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `model` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `length` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `passengers` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `idActor` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `idFilm` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK_car_film` (`idFilm`),
  KEY `FK_car_actor` (`idActor`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

-Cada actor puede conducir muchos coches. Hay actores que tienen 10 coches conducidos de diferentes películas o de la misma película.
-Un coche puede ser conducido por muchos actores diferentes. Hay coches que los han conducido 5 o 6 actores diferentes o el mismo.
-Un actor puede participar en muchas películas diferentes.
-En una película hay muchos actores diferentes.

Comment: Por favor, danos el dataset en SQL, que así cuesta un montón replicarlo :) (phpMyAdmin, Exportar)

Comment: @DavidJP
Lo siento soy nuevo en esto. Estoy utilizando MySQL.
No sé como se hace esto. Veo que tú tienes bastante experiencia.
Así que si me puedes ayudar te lo agradecería mucho.
Gracias.
Un saludo.

Comment: Muy sencillo: vas `http://localhost/phpmyadmin`, seleccionas la base de datos con la que estás trajando, pulsas sobre Exportar y descargarás en fichero de texto plano con extensión .sql, modificas la pregunta copiando y pegando su contenido y ya podremos ayudarte cómodamente...

Comment: @DavidJP
Lo siento pero me accede a localhost.
¿Qué necesitas saber la información de cada tabla con un ejemplo de datos?
yo te lo pongo ahora mismo para que puedas ayudarme.
Gracias. Eres muy amable.

Comment: @DavidJP
Ok, acabo de editar el contenido ahora.
Creo que es lo que me has pedido para ayudarme.
Gracias por ayudarme.
Un saludo.

Comment: Ahora sólo te quedan los datos, tiene que aparecer por ahí algún `INSERT`

Comment: Por cierto, analizando un poco esa base de datos, no entiendo cómo han propagado los campos ni a qué cardinalidades responden: ¿cuánto coches puede conducir cada actor? ¿Por cuántos actores puede ser conducido un coche? Y lo mismo con las películas... ¿dónde está el truco? ¿Tienes el modelo ER al que se supone que responde este diseño?

Comment: @DavidJP
Cada actor puede conducir muchos coches. Hay actores que tienen 10 coches conducidos de diferentes películas o de la misma película.
Un coche puede ser conducido por muchos actores diferentes. Hay coches que los han conducido 5 o 6 actores diferentes o el mismo.
Un actor puede participar en muchas películas diferentes.
En una película hay muchos actores diferentes.

Comment: Pues, en ese caso, te faltan tablas (al menos una) y te sobran algunos campos `Id` en las que ya tienes. Tienes un problema de diseño, por eso la consulta no te sale

Comment: @DavidJP
¿Qué tablas me faltan y qué campo me sobran?
Creo que tengo que hacer con estas tres tablas: film, car y cctor

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107925/discussion-between-javi-and-david-jp).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La consulta que estás buscando para identificar:

> En las pelis 'a todo gas' y 'la carrera', ¿qué actor(es) conduce(n) el coche
>   que más veces aparece en las películas seleccionadas?

Sería:

```
SELECT DISTINCT actor FROM conducen_actuando
  JOIN actores USING(id_actor)
  WHERE id_coche IN (
    SELECT id_coche FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT id_pelicula,id_coche
          FROM conducen_actuando
          WHERE id_pelicula IN (
           SELECT id_pelicula FROM peliculas
            WHERE pelicula IN ('A todo gas','La Carrera')      
          )  
      ) c1
      GROUP BY 1 HAVING COUNT(*)=(
        SELECT MAX(n) FROM (
            SELECT id_coche,COUNT(*) n FROM (
                SELECT DISTINCT id_pelicula,id_coche
                  FROM conducen_actuando
                  WHERE id_pelicula IN (
                   SELECT id_pelicula FROM peliculas
                    WHERE pelicula IN ('A todo gas','La Carrera')      
                  )  
              ) c1
              GROUP BY 1  
          ) c1  
      )    
  );
```

Sobre un modelo de datos como éste:

[image: Diagrama DB]

Que se puede replicar con este SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE actores (
  id_actor INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  actor VARCHAR(31) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id_actor)
);
CREATE TABLE coches (
  id_coche INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  coche VARCHAR(31) DEFAULT NULL,
  fabricante VARCHAR(31) DEFAULT NULL,
  modelo VARCHAR(31) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id_coche)
);
CREATE TABLE peliculas (
  id_pelicula INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  pelicula VARCHAR(31) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id_pelicula)
);
CREATE TABLE conducen_actuando (
  id_pelicula INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  id_actor INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  id_coche INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  id_conducen_actuando INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (id_conducen_actuando),
  INDEX id_actor (id_actor),
  INDEX id_coche (id_coche),
  INDEX id_pelicula (id_pelicula),
  CONSTRAINT conducen_actuando_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (id_pelicula)
    REFERENCES peliculas(id_pelicula) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT conducen_actuando_ibfk_2 FOREIGN KEY (id_actor)
    REFERENCES actores(id_actor) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT conducen_actuando_ibfk_3 FOREIGN KEY (id_coche)
    REFERENCES coches(id_coche) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT
);
```

Y estos datos:

```
INSERT INTO actores VALUES
(1, 'Vin Diesel'),
(2, 'Dwayne Johnson'),
(3, 'Paul walker');
INSERT INTO coches VALUES
(1, 'A8', 'Audi', 'A8'),
(2, 'Testarossa', 'Ferrari', 'Testarossa'),
(3, 'M3', 'BMW', 'M3'),
(4, 'CLK', 'Mercedes', 'CLK');
INSERT INTO peliculas VALUES
(1, 'A todo gas'),
(2, 'Carretera al infierno'),
(3, 'La Carrera');
INSERT INTO conducen_actuando VALUES
(1, 1, 2, 1),
(1, 2, 1, 2),
(2, 3, 2, 3),
(1, 2, 4, 6),
(3, 2, 4, 7);
```

Resultando:

```
Dwayne Johnson
```

En tu diseño faltaba la tabla de relación `conducen_actuando` que recopilaría todos los campos `id` que tenías diseminados por las diferentes tablas de entidades. Espero que te resulte útil.