# Relación ternaria o binaria de un enunciado

Tags: base-de-datos

quisiera consultar con respecto a modelar en DER una relación ternaria entre estudiantes, curso y exámenes. No tengo experiencia en relaciones ternarias y ver si la descomposición en binaria de la misma esta correcta:

[image: DER relación ternaria y binaria]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es así. La relación entre exámenes, cursos y alumnos no debe ser una relación ternaria.

Hay muchas razones que lo demuestran. Por ejemplo, un examen solo pertenece a un curso. Solo por eso ya no se trata de una relación ternaria. Otras razones son que un alumno solo puede hacer exámenes de los cursos en que esté cursando.

Recuerda, para que una relación ternaria tenga sentido, debe cumplirse la máxima:

Cualquier alumno puede hacer cualquier examen de cualquier curso. Y cualquier curso puede tener cualquier examen de cualquier alumno. Ya ves, que esas máximas no se cumplen.

Si quieres, puedes consultar un libro que publiqué hace años en  http://algorismes.cat, allí todo esto se explica detalladamente.

De hecho, ninguno de los dos diagramas que muestras es correcto. El de la ternaria, descartado. El de las binarias tiene un ciclo. Que en un modelo ER haya un ciclo significa que hay redundancia de información. Y la redundancia en las bases relacionales es mala consejera.

Si no fuese necesario guardar los estudiantes inscritos en algún curso en el que no se hayan presentado a ningún examen, entonces el diagrama podría ser

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con ese diagrama solo podríamos saber que un estudiante se matriculó de un curso si se presentó a alguno de los exámenes del curso. Y como ventaja, no hay redundancia de información.

Y si por el contrario deseamos mantener el registro de los estudiantes en los cursos aunque no se presenten a ningún examen, entonces tendríamos que añadir dos atributos a la relación examen, que relacionaría cursos y alumnos y sería M:N. Así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los valores del atributo examen serían "primer parcial", "segundo parcial", etcétera, por ejemplo. Todo eso significa una sola tabla que apunte a otras dos. El inconveniente, que para los que no se presenten, guardarás dos nulos. Como eso parece poco frecuente, yo diría que esta es la mejor solución.

Espero que sirva.

Respondo aquí a DavidJP por ser la mía una respuesta demasiado extensa:

La implementación final resulta la misma siempre y cuando el atributo "examen"  se restrinja a un mismo conjunto de valores para todos los cursos, de acuerdo. Pero incluso en ese caso, mejor definir un dominio para el atributo examen en la relación.

Si ese no es el caso, por ejemplo si el curso "Biología" tiene un examen llamado "Biología Molecular", entonces no cabe relación ternaria en ningún caso. Consecuencia de ese error de diseño es que cada vez que apareciese un examen en la relación, el curso sería el mismo y eso es redundancia. Y como un curso concreto aparecerá tantas veces como estudiantes haya, guardaremos todas esas veces la información que ese examen pertenece a ese curso.

Y respeto a la redundancia en el caso del modelo ER con el ciclo, existiría  para cualquier alumno que se presentase a cualquier examen, puesto que podríamos saber que el alumno se ha matriculado al curso de dos formas distintas.

Si lo que prendiésemos es controlar explícitamente que no se puedan presentar los que no están matriculados, entonces esa redundancia sería útil para el control de ese tipo de errores. Como ocurre siempre, la redundancia sirve para el control de errores. Todo CRC es redundante, como lo es la letra de nuestro NIF, que también es un CRC. Pero aun así, aunque quisiéramos controlar que los que se presentan están matriculados, la solución M:N es más concisa que el diagrama con el ciclo, por usar menos tablas.

Comment: muchas gracias por su tiempo y explicación de la problemática, que este muy bien!!!

Comment: @carles es un honor conocerte, estoy deseando leer tu libro http://algorismes.cat/bases_de_dades_cartesianes/Bases%20de%20Datos%20Cartesianas%20(Carles%20Franquesa).pdf

Comment: Me gustaría trasladarte una par de cuestiones sobre la solución que propones pues, aunque afirmas que no debe ser una relación ternaria, se termina llegando a la misma implementación física a la que se llegaría, precisamente, con la misma relación ternaria que comienzas desestimando. Por otra parte, ¿qué redundancias identificas en el modelo con relaciones binarias? No todos los bucles implican necesariamente redundancia. De hecho, en el modelo propuesto por el OP no he logrado identificar ninguna. Saludos

Answer (score 2):

Aunque ambos diagramas modelan perfectamente el problema, yo lo implementaría con las relaciones binarias porque, en este caso, se adaptan mejor a la realidad:

- La relación `inscribe` modela fielmente el proceso de matriculación, pues no es necesario realizar ningún examen para matricularse en un curso
- La relación `tiene` describe qué exámenes requiere un curso para ser superado
- Con `presenta` sabes qué alumnos se han presentado a cada examen

En cambio, en la relación ternaria `ECE`:

- Si aún no hay ningún alumno matriculado o si ningún alumno se ha presentado aún a ningún examen, ¿cómo registras qué exámenes requiere cada curso? ¿Usando nulos?
- ¿Cómo sabrías si un alumno se ha presentado a todos los exámenes? ¿Y su nota media?
- ¿Cómo calcularías cuántos alumnos tienes matriculados?

¿Ves que ya tienes que andar haciendo arreglillos con los `NULL` que te complican consultas que deberían ser prácticamente inmediatas? Sin embargo, la propuesta en relaciones binarias, además de ser más sencilla de implementar y entender, resulta más natural de cumplimentar.

Por otra parte, sabes que la relación `tiene` terminará reduciéndose, por propagación al tener cardinalidad 1:N, a un campo en `examen`.

Resumiendo: usa cardinalidades ternarias cuando sea imposible modelar tu problema en binarias. Cuando te encuentres con una ternaria, la reconocerás, créeme: [Buscar quien es el actor que conduce el coche que más veces aparece en un listado de peliculas películas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/354989)

Comment: Muchas gracias por su tiempo y por la explicación desde ya que se encuentre muy bien!!